# Jenkins and TFS connetion

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

**Jenkins and TFS connetion**

I am trying to connect and build a project using jenkins and TFS.

I am periodically build it. And i got this error:

Querying for remote changeset at '$/TheSpectrumCareer/Portal' as of 'D2019-10-23T09:07:01Z'...

FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection timed out: connect

Is there any way of doing it right.

**I expect the output as below:**

```
> Querying for remote changeset at '$/TheSpectrumCareer/Portal' as of
> 'D2019-10-16T04:33:53Z'... Query result is: Changeset #12532 by
> 'WEBTEAMCORP\drashtipatel' on '2019-07-30T10:22:54Z'. Checking if
> there exists a mapping for
> <http://localhost:8081/job/TSC%20Admin/ws/...yes,> in workspace
> 'Hudson-TSC Admin-MASTER'. Downloading list of workspaces from
> http://assetmanagement.webteamcorp.com:8080/tfs/DotNetCollection...
> Getting version 'C12532' to
> '<http://localhost:8081/job/TSC%20Admin/ws/'...> Finished getting
> version 'C12532'. Retrieved 0 resources. Email was triggered for:
> Before Build Sending email for trigger: Before Build Request made to
> compress build log An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of
> recipients, ignored. Path To MSBuild.exe:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe Executing
> the command cmd.exe /C "
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln
> " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from
> <http://localhost:8081/job/TSC%20Admin/ws/> [TSC Admin] $ cmd.exe /C "
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln
> " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
> 4.0.30319.18408 [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> 
> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
> parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. Build started 10/16/2019
> 12:34:04 AM. Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> on node 1 (default targets). ValidateSolutionConfiguration:   Building
> solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU". Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> (1) is building
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (2) on node 1 (default targets).
> GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: Skipping target
> "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
> up-to-date with respect to the input files. CoreCompile: Skipping
> target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with
> respect to the input files.
> _CopyAppConfigFile: Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
> CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:   RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers ->
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers\bin\Debug\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.dll
> Done Building Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (default targets). Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> (1) is building
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (3) on node 1 (default targets).
> GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: Skipping target
> "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
> up-to-date with respect to the input files. CoreCompile: Skipping
> target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with
> respect to the input files. CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:  
> RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers ->
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers\bin\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers.dll
> Done Building Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.Service.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (default targets). Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> (1) is building
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (4) on node 1 (default targets). EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources:
> Skipping target "EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources" because it has no
> outputs. EntityDeployEmbeddedResources: Skipping target
> "EntityDeployEmbeddedResources" because all output files are
> up-to-date with respect to the input files.
> GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: Skipping target
> "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
> up-to-date with respect to the input files. CoreCompile: Skipping
> target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with
> respect to the input files.
> _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways:   Copying file from "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\js\jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
> to "bin\js\jquery-1.11.3.min.js".   Copying file from
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\Content\thespectrumcareers-f23236747252.p12"
> to "bin\Content\thespectrumcareers-f23236747252.p12".
> CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:   RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers ->
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\bin\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers.dll
> Done Building Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers.csproj"
> (default targets). Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> (1) is building
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\UnitTest\TestWithJenkins\TestWithJenkins.csproj"
> (5) on node 1 (default targets).
> GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: Skipping target
> "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
> up-to-date with respect to the input files. CoreCompile: Skipping
> target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with
> respect to the input files.
> _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways:   Copying file from "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\js\jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
> to "bin\Debug\js\jquery-1.11.3.min.js".   Copying file from
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.WebAdmin.TheSpectrumCareers\Content\thespectrumcareers-f23236747252.p12"
> to "bin\Debug\Content\thespectrumcareers-f23236747252.p12".
> _CopyAppConfigFile: Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
> CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:   TestWithJenkins ->
> D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\UnitTest\TestWithJenkins\bin\Debug\TestWithJenkins.dll
> Done Building Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\UnitTest\TestWithJenkins\TestWithJenkins.csproj"
> (default targets). Done Building Project
> "D:\Vaibhavi\Projects\WTC_TheSpectrumCareer\RCI.Library.TheSpectrumCareers.sln"
> (default targets).
> 
> Build succeeded.
>     0 Warning(s)
>     0 Error(s)
> 
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.77
```

Comment: Log looks not like TFS side, are you build your project in Jenkins and get source from TFS code repo? `Querying for remote changeset at '$/TheSpectrumCareer/Portal' as...
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection timed out: connect` According to the error seems you failed to connect with TFS sever, please double check the connection between TFS server side and Jenkins server. Make sure the network is ok and you could also use web portal to access TFS instead through Jenkins build, check if your Jenkins build service account is able `$/TheSpectrumCareer/Portal`.

Comment: Yes My TFS and jenkins connection fails, but this scenario is generated around 90 times frmo 100 times, and only 10 times connection is established and actual build is produced.

Comment: Hi  Vaibhavi Raval , for this scenario, it seems more likely a environment issue. Like network, firewall. You may consider to track a fiddler log to analysis and narrow down the issue. Could also involve your IT team to troubleshoot. Since it not related to TFS side, once connection is established and actual build is produced. Suggest to remove unrelated TFS tag.